# Default Ringtone Preference to silent

Tags: android, android-preferences, ringtone

I have a ringtone preference in a preferences.xml that currently defaults to the system notification sound.

I'd like to default it to silent, but am having trouble finding the content URI to the silent sound.

```
    <RingtonePreference
            android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
            android:key="@string/pref_alarm_tone_scan_notification_sound"
            android:ringtoneType="notification"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:showSilent="true"
            android:title="@string/pref_alarm_notification_sound_title" />
```

In a subclass of Application, I am setting the default values from the xml file as follows:

```
// apply defaults as stored in preferences.xml
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071707/ringtone-preference-defaults-to-silent-even-though-defaultvalue-set

Comment: That link is an issue of someone not calling setDefaultValues(). I actually want mine to default to silent (and apply the other defaults in my preferences.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the silent sound is an empty string

```
android:defaultValue=""
```